# Any way to locate an error with filename unknown in Unity? - related to dictionary same key exists

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to revive a old project written by another person, this was in Unity Version 5.2.1f1.

Edited: Opening it for the first time, I have this error related to "Dictionary with the same key already exists."

Since it was written by another person, I can't do any "remember where I worked with dictionaries" type of tracing.

If you were to encounter this problem, what other ways would you do to trace the dictionary error? Are there any special tools or hacks we can do to be able to dig deeper with this compile error?

```
 Error: System.ArgumentException: An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary.
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String].Add (System.String key, System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
       at us.UnityScriptCompilerFactory.FromCommandLineOptions (us.CommandLineOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
       at us.UsModule.compile (us.CommandLineOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
       at us.UsModule.runWithCommandLine (System.String[] commandLine) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
       at us.UsModule.Main (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Not sure how to trace it because the filename is unknown. Is there any way to locate where this is?(doubling clicking didn't get me to the error line).

Comment: The question you are asking is quite vague, given the error output you've given. The issue in question is that you have a key conflict with the dictionary being used. There is no information available to any reader given in order to help you trace file name or scripts likely failing. Consider posting the full error stack for a higher chance of others helping you on this one.

Comment: Hi @ScottBarnes thanks for taking your time. The more I research I learn more that my question being "off"- so I edited it and hopefully it would make more sense.

Since it was written by another person, I can't do any "remember where I worked with dictionaries" type of tracing.

If you were to encounter this problem, what other ways would you do to trace the dictionary error? Are there any special tools or hacks we can do to be able to dig deeper with this compile error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the code there is a dictionary. You are trying to add an entry using a key that already exists in the dictionary (duplicate key entry) and this is crashing your program.

Comment: Hi @vasmos, if in the scenario where you didn't know where that dictionary error is, what steps can you suggest to find it?

Comment: This one is tough because it says filename unknown, perhaps its coming from some kind of plugin or dll?

Comment: Yeah I was worried that it might be coming from a plugin or dll.

Answer (score 0):

To add precision to vasmos's answer and
whithout any other precisions on your code,

to know and find if you have a duplicate key in your dictionary you could use:
[ContainsKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.containskey?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_2_ContainsKey__0_)

```
if (dico.ContainsKey(key)) 
{ ... }
```

or use [TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.trygetvalue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_2_TryGetValue__0__1__)

```
dico.TryGetValue(key, out value);
```

Comment: Good duplicate of my answer